# React native not persisting user data from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

So i am buidling a mobile app using Expo react native and firebase, i am having a issue with current user not presisting data. following are a few code snippets:

App.js:

```
import { AuthContextProvider } from "./context/AuthContext";
import MainNavigator from "./screens/MainNavigator";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <MainNavigator />
    </AuthContextProvider>
  );
}
```

AuthContext.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { onAuthStateChanged, getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import firebase_app from "../firebase/config";
const auth = getAuth(firebase_app);
import { Text } from "react-native";

export const AuthContext = React.createContext({});
export const useAuthContext = () => React.useContext(AuthContext);

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
      } else {
        setUser(null);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user }}>
      {loading ? <Text>Loading...</Text> : children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

How i access the user:

```
const { user } = useAuthContext();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(user);
  }, []);
```

This user presists after i login but as soon as i reload or reopen the app the user is null

Firebase version: 10.0.0

As per the documentation we can set the persistant to different mode and the default is local still then i set the persistant to local but didnt work.

I am expecting the user to keep its state even after the app is reloaded as the user is saved inside of async storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution myself, Firebase 10.0.0 is not working properly, upgrade to 10.1.0 and it works